# Transform CSS property doesn't work with <a> element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to `scale(x,y)` my `<a>` element when I click on it, but it doesn't work. I use Mozilla Firefox web browser to run the program.

Here is my code:

### scaleElement.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS3 Transform and Transition</title>
        <style>
            a{
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                text-decoration: none;
                border: 2px solid #85ADFF;
                border-radius: 30px 10px;
                transition: 2s;
            }
            a:hover{
                transform: scale(2,2);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><a href="xyz.html">click here</a></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is not applicable to inline elements such as `<a>`. You could display the link as `inline-block` or `block` to get transform to work:

> **[transformable element](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transformable-element)**
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a **block-level** or **atomic inline-level** element, or whose display
>     property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>     table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [...]

Where [atomic inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13) elements include:

> replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and
>   inline-table elements

```
a { display: inline-block; }
a:hover { transform: scale(2,2); }
```

Besides, there's no *on-click* state available in CSS. Possible options are `:active` or `:hover`, or using [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

```css
a {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #85ADFF;
  border-radius: 30px 10px;
  transition: all 2s;
  display: inline-block; /* <-- added declaration */
}
a:hover{ transform: scale(2,2); }
/* just for demo */
body { padding: 2em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<a href="xyz.html">click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks...it's run properly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `display:block` and give it a height and width

```css
a {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #85ADFF;
  border-radius: 30px 10px;
  transition: 2s all ease-in;
  display: block;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
a:hover {
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

```html
<center><a href="xyz.html">click here</a>
</center>
```