# Css text zoom effect snapping back when hovering

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to make my headers on a website zoom in on hover. I must be doing something wrong. When I hold the mouse over the text the text is zoomed in (or enlarged if you will) but then it snaps back to the original size again.

I want it to snap back to the original size, but only when I remove the mouse from the text. This should be pretty basic but, I guess I am missing something here.

How can I avoid making the text snap back to the original size when the mouse is over the text?

```css
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      clear: both;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.2;
      margin-bottom: 3%;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 50px; /*Originally 50px*/
    }
    
    .entry-title {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-size: 43px; /*Originally 80px*/
      font-weight: 700;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      line-height: 1.1;
      margin-bottom: 0%;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .entry-title {
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
    .entry-title a {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      color: #404040;
      text-decoration: none;
      -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
      -o-transition:-o-transform 0.2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.2s ease-out; 
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out; 
      -o-transition:-o-transform 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    .entry-title a:hover {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-shadow:1px 0px #555;
      -moz-transform:scale(1.03); 
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.03);
      -o-transform:scale(1.03);
    }
```

```html
    <h1 class="entry-title">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">This is a sample text</a>
    </h1>
```

Comment: You can refer with the following link which is already existing  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this and you will get what you need.

```
.entry-title a {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

Refference [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/spzm9/)

Comment: Perfect! And thanks for cleaning up the unnecessary lines haha.

Comment: @Leo the lion any idea why `transform: scale()` doesn't work on inline elements?

Comment: @gaynorvader9 please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667859/transform-css-property-doesnt-work-with-a-element and you will know why..sorry for link as can't explain in comment..hope you can understand..ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/4gsrb39o/).

```
a {
  font - size: 18 px
  font - family: 'Oswald', sans - serif;
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s, font-size 2s;
  -moz-transition: color 2s, font-size 2s;
  -o-transition: color 2s, font-size 2s;
  transition: color 2s, font-size 2s;
}
a:hover {
  font-size: 45px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to sort of work. The only problem is that my text is inside a div and I have more divs below. When the text is enlarged the rest of the content in the div is pushed downwards. Does that make any sense?